# Returning value from promise chain

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await

I have a database connection for the Ojai client in node-js where i have a lot of promises, that needs to be resolved in order to establish the connection

```
const getAllStatuses = async (connectionString, tablename) =>{
   let connection;
   return ConnectionManager.getConnection(connectionString)
    .then(conn =>{
        connection = conn;
        return connection.getStore(tablename)
    }).then(newStore =>{
        const store = newStore;
        return store.find({})
    }).then(queryResult =>{
        queryResult.on('data', (document =>{
        return document
        }))
    }).finally(()=>{
        connection.close()
    })
}
```

right now i have this in a file called `databaseMapper.js`

I can't seem to figure out how to return a value from this promise chainging, because i get `undefined` in my controller.

```
module.exports.getAll = async () =>{
    const data = await databaseMapper.getAllStatuses(connectionString, tables.status)
    console.log(data)
    return data
}
```

I have tried to make the function `async` and then `await` the promise, but stil with no luck.

Can anybody help me achieve me return the correct value (i have tested with console log, that a value is actually returned)

Comment: Your `queryResult.on('data', (document => {` is callback-based, Putting it inside a `.then` doesn't automatically connect it to the Promise chain outside - instead, construct a Promise that resolves when the `.on` fires

Comment: The problem is that your last fulfillment handler (the one calling `on`) has no `return` in it. There's a `return` in the callback you're passing `on`, but not in the fulfillment handler you're passing `then`. So that implicitly returns `undefined`, which becomes the fulfillment value of the promise chain. You'll need to wrap that `on` call in a promise to use it with a promise chain. (Also, since `getAllStatuses` is an `async` function, you can use `await` rather than `.then`, and `try`/`finally` rather than `.finally`.)

Comment: Also note that your code doesn't quite handle `getConnection` rejections correctly; your `finally` handler tries to call `close` on `undefined` in that case. The error that generates is suppressed, though, since there's already an error in progress and it's in a `finally` handler. Separately, given how much of the API you're using is already promise-based, I suspect there's a promise-based alternative to that `on` callback API. But if not, it's simple enough to write a wrapper function, something along these lines: https://pastebin.com/EZZ913Ej

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Perfect! thank you. If you post as answer i will accept!

Comment: @baileyhaldwin - The question is closed, so it's not possible to post an answer. :-) But I figured the comment would be helpful. Happy coding!

Comment: @T.J.Crowder is it possible to do this, if it returns multiple `document` s?

Comment: @baileyhaldwin - I assume so, I don't know ojai. If there can be multiple `data` events, I'm guessing you could keep them in an array (or similar) and then resolve the project in response to an `end` event or something.

Comment: yes exactly what i figured.. But for the `queryResult.on()` is it possible to map these?

Comment: i tried something like this `function queryResultPromise(queryResult) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let data = []
        queryResult.on("data", doc => data.push(doc));
        queryResult.on("end", (resolve(data)))
        // ...presumably something here to hook an error event and call `reject`...
    });
}` but it returned an empty array